# When someone says "That makes/doesn't make sense" is that more subjective or more objective?

Tags: objectivity, subjectivity

For example what if someone said "That makes sense" in response to saying "The pot will burn you if you touch it because it's hot." I'm inclined to say objective but it's possible someone could disagree with it making sense because they aren't familiar with the concept.

Comment: Wouldn't this just depend on if the original subject is objective or subjective?

Comment: "What **doesn't make sense** is that the world **makes sense**"~Albert, the genius, Einstein.

Comment: Doesn't this entirely depend on the someone and what they say it about?

Comment: Typically it's a subjective statement like "I understand", but by which a second person agrees on a claim about objective truth with a first person. That way, 2 people mutually agree on what both believe henceforth to be objective truth (or at least potential truth).

Comment: You may find this collection useful https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/65999/37256